# Why jquery .push() not working in this case?

Tags: jquery, push

I have the below code where it adds items to a json string,

```
function addOrder(req, orderId, orderSource, transactiondtm) {
    alert(orderId);
    req.Request.orderslist.push({ ordid: orderId,
                               ordsource: orderSource,
                               tranndtm: transactiondtm });
}
function getDisplayPts(){

    var req = {
              "Request": {
                "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                "number": Num,
                "orderslist": {
                  "ordid":        [],
                  "ordsource":    [],
                  "tranndtm": []
                }
              }
            };
    $('#msListingProducts ul.msRows li input').each(function(index) {

        addOrder(req,$('#hfOrderId'+index).val(),$('#hfOrderSource'+index).val(),$('#hfOrdTranDate'+index).val());
        });
    var str = JSON.stringify(req);
    alert(str);
    }
```

I am getting `req.Request.orderslist.push()` is not a function.. Any suggestion.. For Some rows orderId is coming as undefined is it because of that?

**EDIT:**
My required json format is,

```
{
  "Request": {
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "memNum": "70000211981",
    "orderslist": [
      {
        "ordid": "511",
        "ordsource": "ONLINE",
        "transactiondttm": "2014-01-09"
      },
      {
        "ordid": "512",
        "ordersource": "STORE",
        "tranndttm": "2014-01-09"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to access object element as an array so it is giving an error. Here 'req.Request.orderslist' is an object and .push() method is to push data into array so it is giving an error. To solve it make 'req.Request.orderslist' an array and then push records in it.

Comment: @SohilDesai Can you explain that plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to access object element as an array so it is giving an error.  When you prepare an object req it should be like this

```
var req = {
          "Request": {
            "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
            "number": Num,
            "orderslist": []
          }
        };
```

Now, you can use push method.

Answer (score 1):

`orderslist` is an `object` in your context, you cannot `push` anything into it. But you can push the values into the following,

```
req.Request.orderslist.ordid.push(orderId)
req.Request.orderslist.ordsource.push(orderSource)
req.Request.orderslist.tranndtm.push(transactiondtm)
```

Comment: you needs to [push the `value` has a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21153114/1671639)

Answer (score 1):

`.push()` is meant for `array` whereas `orderslist`  is `object` in your case. Hence it is not working.

But `ordid, ordsource, tranndtm` are array.  So

```
req.Request.orderslist.ordid.push(orderId)
req.Request.orderslist.ordsource.push(orderSource)
req.Request.orderslist.tranndtm.push(transactiondtm)
```

Comment: @coderman I still don't what is making what is causing the problem.  however I have made a http://jsfiddle.net/Nj2w7/ to make it easier.